# Finding the normality with Kernal density estimator

Tags: r

I have used the density() function and I got two plots: density of y, and density of residuals. If I am interested in the normality of the data, which plot should I look at ? Is the density of y the same as normal Q-Q plot?

I think it's the density plot of y as it is about the data, but why do I also need to look at the density of residuals too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> which plot should I look at ?

Depends. If you're interested in the normality of the data, use `y`. If you're interested in the normality of the residuals (say, for model assessment), use the residuals. It's probably the case you want to determine whether you have a decent model, so you should look at the residuals.

It would be helpful if you gave a little bit more on the model you are using. If you're doing something like a linear model, then you usually assume the residuals are normal, but not necessarily the data `y`. It would be perfectly reasonable to have `y` not be normal, but have normal residuals.

The density plot is not the same as the Q-Q plot, but both could be helpful in diagnosing normality. Though, you'll have success with Q-Q since it gives a better idea of how the tails might deviate from the normal distribution.